# Change the size of a math symbol

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How can I get something like in the figure, where G in the middle is larger than normal letters in math mode?

[image]

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `\mathlarger` command from `relsize`. If you want to have a choice for the new size, you can use the `\text{}` command, change the text font size and insert a math formula inside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}%


 \begin{document}

\[ F \longrightarrow \text{\Large$ G $}\longrightarrow H \]

\[ F \longrightarrow \mathlarger{G}\longrightarrow H \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The package `relsize` can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$F\to \text{\larger[2]$G$} \to H$
\\
$F\to \mathlarger{G} \to H$
\\
$F\to \mathlarger{\mathlarger{G}} \to H$
\end{center}
\begin{gather}
F\to \text{\larger[2]$G$} \to H
\\
F\to \mathlarger{G} \to H
\\
F\to \mathlarger{\mathlarger{G}} \to H
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

The first three lines emulate inline math mode, centered for easier comparison, whereas the second group of three formulas emulate display math mode.

You can notice that a single `\mathlarger` doesn't change the size in inline math, so probably you want to go for

```
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{G}}
```

Of course, you want to make a new command for it:

```
\newcommand{\bigletter}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bigG}{\bigletter{G}}
```

This way you can delay the final choice to the last minute.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'd say: you have to encapsulate the letter in the middle in a `\mbox`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  F \rightarrow \mbox{\Large$G$} \rightarrow H
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: since the "G" is math, it should really be `\Large$G$`.

Answer (score 2):

In case that you need a non standard size (as those that you can obtain with commands like `\text{\Large$G$}`) a simple solution to obtain any size is a `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\( F \longrightarrow \text{\LARGE\ensuremath G} \longrightarrow H \)\par
\( F \longrightarrow \scalebox{1.9}{\ensuremath G} \longrightarrow H \)\par
\( F \longrightarrow \text{\huge\ensuremath G} \longrightarrow H \)
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]