# Minion Pro - how to make the angle symbol the same height as text?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, formatting, minionpro

I am using the [minion pro package](https://ctan.org/pkg/minionpro?lang=en) and noticed that when you use `\angle`, the resulting symbol is not the same height as the text as it is for computer modern, as seen in the below picture.

[image]

What can I do the make the symbol the same height as the text, as seen below for CM?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? **(1)** [Change the size of a math symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348108/change-the-size-of-a-math-symbol) or **(2)** [Rescaling a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112580) or **(3)** [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have tried those but it doesn't seem to get it to look how I want (like it does in CM).  Is it perhaps possible to change the symbol to one from another font?

Comment: I am sure there are already similar questions regarding this. Maybe have look or provide some code that shows what you have tried. I suggest that you provide more context, such as compiler (luatex, pdftex etc) and document class.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner scaling does make it bigger, but the symbol does not get aligned to the bottom of the other characters. As you can see in the sample above, the angle sign seems to be aligned in the middle, and scaling it does not change the position of the bottom of the character.

Comment: The accepted answer in the second link shows how to adjust the vertical position: The \larger command seems to have an optional argument. Maybe this is helpful in your case.